# iPhone - Access File from Protocol Request

Tags: iphone, ios, file, protocols

I am building an iPhone app, and I am trying to have a web view with embedded content, and I am trying to have a file returned from when a web view requests a file from the applications protocol. For example, `protocol://app/style.css` would return the contents of `style.css` in the Application Bundle, while `protocol://documents/folder/image.png` would access the file `folder/image.png` from the applications documents directory.

The Spotify Mac application does it with their apps, allowing developers to access the Spotify styling with an address similar to the `//app/style.css` method above. When the method is called from within the app, the styling file is returned, while when called outside of the app, then the application is simply launched.

How can I include a file from my main application bundle into a web view by having the web view location set to `customProtocol://app/style.css`?

Comment: How can I include a file from my main application bundle into a web view by having the web view location set to `customProtocol://app/style.css` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a JS replace function, to replace `protocol://` with real path string

set `webView.delegate = self;`
Then in `webViewDidFinishLoad` replace the `protocol://` with real path

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //Get the real path
    NSString *exactPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Document/CorrectPath/"];

    //In head replace protocol with real path
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML.replace('protocol://','%@')", exactPath];

    //Execute javascript replace on head
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

Comment: I will try this, but I feel like web pages in frames are also sandboxed, giving them no access to the system or other applications' files. I have not checked that either yet, so I could be wrong.